# Azure ADF timeout option for IF condition step

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have any Azure Data Factory pipeline setup where there is if condition used in 3 places. So the ADF pipeline runs on daily basis and once in a while we have this the if condition run for around 2-3 hours before we manually cancel and re-run it. On re-running the if condition gets succeeded in under 10 seconds. Could you please help me understand if there is any option for timeout in "IF condition" or is there any way we can build it?

Tried checking the timeout option in settings, but couldn't find any such option.(we thought there will be timeout option same as we see for Copy activity in ADF. but didn't find any)

Expectation is to have the pipeline IF condition timeout in say 10 minutes if not run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

**AFAIK, there is no built-in feature to pit timeout on if condition.**

**To resolve this, you can use below workaround by wrapping If activity with until activity by passing timeout to it.**

Here I declared one variable with Boolean value false.

[image]

Then pass this value to until loop to check and set a timeout to it.

[image]

under this pass if activity and give your expression to check. And place your activities under if activity.

[image]

here I created infinite loop with help of set variable but when until activity reach the timeout it stops the execution.

[image]